# Post from OpenId not firing OWIN Layer on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin, katana

I have problem with Katana OWIN. I use it with OpenId server with configuration:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {            
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {

            ClientId = "implicitclient",
            //ClientSecret = "secret",
            Authority = Constants.OpenIdAdress2,
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost/TestApp",
            ResponseType = "id_token token",
            Scope = "openid email",

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

        });

    }
```

When I use it in IIS Express from Visual Studio 2012 everything is OK. When I change host to IIS 7.5 over Win8, My Thinktecture server post me back code and OWIN doesn't recognize this post to MVC application,

I use package:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="3.0.0-rc2" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Have anyone idea what I'm doing wrong?